In this movie, man accidentally watches woman have breakdown in her home
I remember watching a movie, possibly tv, in the 2000-s. UK movie (or accent of actors). 
A man bumps into a woman on a busy street. She drops her phone. He tries to give it back but she is in a hurry. He goes to her house. She comes back home. He is considering giving her the phone but she starts crying, and while she is going through drinks and tears, he watches hidden in the closet. 
The next day he finds her in the city, gives the phone back - but then she recognizes the scent of his cigarettes. 
Which movie is this?

This movie is called Miss Monday. It was written and directed by Benson Lee. I couldn't think of the name of it until I remembered that "Monday" was in the title. The plot is listed below: Trapped, frustrated and isolated, for one disturbing, slow night these two main characters find that they have more in common than they think. Forced to rummage for research in London's City district for his new screenplay, here, we find human anguish mixed with quiet disbelief. This, a sobering experience of a subject with mixed emotions of her childhood past and future prospects spilling over the precipice of sanity. Haunted by her own personal bogeyman and hidden demons, as the screenwriter is forced to hide in the bedroom cupboard and slowly watch the unraveling of a woman lost, tormented and pained.

Thanks for a good answer. Could you provide the source of the plot details?
